# Displaying array of button clicks (sets and reps for workout app)

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a mock up of a workout app that tracks the sets and reps of an exercise.

Here is how the layout looks:

[image: layout]

How its gonna work is that when someone presses NEW it creates a new SET. Once the SET is active, you press TAP for the number of reps you did. In order to end the current SET, you press NEW again and start a new SET. In order to finish all your sets, you press END. When you press NEW after tapping a bunch of REPs it updates the TextView (test) with the number. That's the basic gist of what I'm trying to do.

I'm trying to keep my data in a integer array of length 5. The array's index is the SET number and the value at the index is the number of REPs.

EXAMPLE: I press NEW (array index is 1), I TAP 5 times (value at index 1 = 5), I press NEW (array at index 2), I TAP 6 times (value at index 2 = 6), and so on...

So my final array values would be something like 5, 6, 5, 3, 5. And I will display that on the TextView.

Here is the code in my Workout.java:

```
 public class Workout extends ActionBarActivity {

    private Button newSet;
    private Button tap;
    private Button end;
    private Integer[] score;
    int clickCount = 0;
    int tapCount = 0;
    boolean endClicked = false;
    TextView displayTest;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_workout);

        score = new Integer[5];

        newSet = (Button)findViewById(R.id.newSetButton);

        displayTest = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.displayScore);


        newSet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                clickCount+=1;
                if (clickCount==1) {
                    score[clickCount]= timesTapped();//replace with number of times tap is clicked
                    displayTest.append(String.valueOf(score[clickCount])); //update view
                }
                else if (clickCount==2) {
                    score[clickCount]= timesTapped(); //replace with number of times tap is clicked
                    displayTest.append(String.valueOf(score[clickCount])); //update view
                }
                else if (clickCount==3) {
                    score[clickCount]= timesTapped(); //replace with number of times tap is clicked
                    displayTest.append(String.valueOf(score[clickCount])); //update view
                }
                else if (clickCount==4) {
                    score[clickCount]= timesTapped(); //replace with number of times tap is clicked
                    displayTest.append(String.valueOf(score[clickCount])); //update view
                }
                else if (clickCount==5) {
                    score[clickCount]= timesTapped(); //replace with number of times tap is clicked
                    displayTest.append(String.valueOf(score[clickCount])); //update view
                }
            }
        });

    }

    //tap button counter method
    public int timesTapped() {

        tap =(Button)findViewById(R.id.tapButton);
        end =(Button)findViewById(R.id.endWorkoutButton);

        tap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tapCount+=1; //update tap count
            }
        });


        newSet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                endClicked = true; //if button is clicked it will display
            }
        });

        if (endClicked == true) {
            return tapCount; //amount to display
        }
        else return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_workout, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

It runs on my emulator without any errors, but it does not do what I think it should. How do get the instancing to work?

If I want to have a SET and then each SET have five values of REPS. How would I go about achieving that? Do I make a new class and then do it from there? If so, how?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You do not ask a specific question... your code does need a lot of help. But you don't even state what it does. It certainly doesn't look like it does what you describe. Please ask a specific question.

Comment: @Jim I want to learn the best way to implement the SET containing REPs thing. For now, I'm having trouble visualizing it. I updated my main post all the way below with a specific question.

Answer (score 0):

why are you complicating it my friend! from what i've understood you simply need to sign the number of clicks on your Tab button to an array index that holds the number of clicks on your new button! but the code isn't related to this at all.

its pretty easy actually, you just need 2 counters one for you Tab button and another for new, and when the user clicks new it add 1 then when user clicks on tab it will add the value to the index and set the flag to true so after clicking another new the `textView` gets updated.

```
    int newIndex=0;
    int tabCount=0;
    int[] score=new Integer[5];
    String result;
    boolean flag=false;
    newSet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            if(flag){
            result+=" "+tabCount+"at"+newIndex+" ";
                textView.setText(result);}
             newIndex+=1;
            }});
    tab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tabCount+=1;
                score[newIndex]=tabCount;
                flag=true;
            }
        });
```

**Note:** the flag is to make sure that the user finished the number of tabs that he wanted, however you can update the `textView` in Tab `onClick()` but that would make the `textView` content inaccurate

Comment: what it says in the logcat ?